# Install Oracle 11g XE on DigitalOcean VPS

Tags: linux, oracle, vps, oracle-xe

I want to deploy the Oracle XE on Digital Ocean VPS running Centos. For some reason I get error when I try to configure it after installation.

These are the log files:

http://pastebin.com/QmQGihJV

http://pastebin.com/vrtU4LL9

http://pastebin.com/CTf6bh74

http://pastebin.com/yqbWhZAu

Do you have any idea how I can solve this issue?

Comment: `(HOST=oracle)`: is the computer's host name really "oracle"?  That name *could* work, but it seems a bit unusual and there are listener errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you trying to reconfigure?

My understanding is you should use

`service oracle-xe configure`

or

`/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure`